# C program wrong output for reading a file

Tags: c

Hello guys so I write this program which purpose is to open a file and read how many characters has in it and print the line with the most and the least characters.I've made it into two functions one for the biggest line and one for the smallest.The "biggest line" function works just fine but I get wrong output for the smallest one.Here is the code:

```
       #include <stdio.h>
       #include <stdlib.h>
       #include <string.h>
       #include <conio.h>
       char f_view[150];
       void ShowResults();
       int leastsymbols();
       int mostsymbols();
       int main(){
       ShowResults();
       return 0;
       }
       int mostsymbols(){
       FILE *fp;
         fp=fopen(f_view, "r");
         if(fp==NULL){
         printf("Error\n");
         exit(-1);
         }
        int lineNO=1;
        int c;
        int currCount=0;
        int highestCount=0;
        int highestline=0;
        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF){
        if (c == '\n') {
        currCount=0;
            lineNO++;
        }

       if (c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c!= ' ') {
       currCount++;
       if(currCount>highestCount){
            highestCount=currCount;
                if(lineNO>highestline){
                    highestline=lineNO;
                    }
                    }
         }
         }
        fclose(fp);
        return highestline;
       }
   int leastsymbols()
    {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(f_view, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
    printf("Could not open file \n");
    exit(-1);
    }
    int c;
    int lineNO = 1;
    int currCount=0;
    int leastLine=0;
    int leastCount=1000;//assuming that a line in a file can not be longer 
                        //than 1000 characters
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF){
    if (c == '\n'){

    currCount = 0;
    lineNO++;
    }
    if (c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c!= ' ') {

    currCount++;

    }
    if(currCount<leastCount){
     leastCount=currCount;
      leastLine=lineNO;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return leastLine;

    }
    void ShowResults()
    {
    FILE *fptr;
    char *fix;
    char c;
    char openFile[1024];
    printf("Type the destination to the *.c file or the file name.\n");
          //the user has to enter a .C file
      while(f_view[strlen(f_view) - 2] != '.' && f_view[strlen(f_view) - 1] 
      != 'c')
    {
      fgets(f_view, 150, stdin);
      fix = strchr(f_view, '\n');
      if(fix != 0)
             *fix = 0;
    }
    if((fptr = fopen(f_view, "r")) == NULL)
    {
      printf("Cannot open file !\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
    int highestLine;
    int lowestLine;
    while (fgets(openFile, 1024, fptr))
    {
      highestLine=mostsymbols();
      lowestLine=leastsymbols();

    }
    printf("Line %d has the most symbols.\n",highestLine);
    printf("Line %d has the least symbols.\n",lowestLine);

    fclose(fptr);
    return ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move this check to when you go to the next line

```
 if(currCount<leastCount){
           leastCount=currCount;
           leastLine=lineNO;
    }
```

your placement is wrong because currCount is at the first iteration is still 1 or 0 depending on what is first character on the line, so it is the smallest and this is for every new line you read

Comment: if (c == '\n'){

        if(currCount<leastCount){

        leastCount=currCount;

        leastLine=lineNO;

        }

        currCount = 0;

        lineNO++;

        }
Something like that?

Comment: I did it.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my program thank you.:)

```
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF){
    if(c == '\n' && currCount<leastCount){
    leastCount=currCount;
    leastLine=lineNO;
    }
    if(c=='\n'){
    currCount = 0;
    lineNO++;
         }
        if (c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c!= ' ') {

    currCount++;

    }
    }
```